# How to get the current user authorities/role and do some calculations according to the role in spring security

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I am doing a project on library management system in spring boot security.
In order to calculate the fines for the issued books according to the roles i wan the current user role after borrowing a book.
Current user name, role book_id and fine  will be stored in other table.
I am able to get the current users username, but not able to get role the current user.

Could someone please help me out!

//Part of Controller class

```
 @RequestMapping("/homepage/borrowBook")
            public String addBookings(Bookings bk, HttpServletRequest rqst) {
                rqst.setAttribute("mode", "MODE_BORROW");
                return "homepage";
            }
    @PostMapping("/homepage/save-borrow")
        public String saveBorrow(Bookings bk, HttpServletRequest rqst, Authentication auth) {
            rqst.setAttribute("mode", "MODE_BORROW");
            if (BookRepo.exists(bk.getBook_id())) {
                bk.setUser(auth.getName());

/////here i want the current user authority to be saved/checked.
                bookingsRepo.save(bk);
                return "homepage";
            } else {
                rqst.setAttribute("error", "Book doesn't exist");

                return "homepage";
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Authentication.getAuthorities()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.4.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.html#getAuthorities--) to get the roles of the currently logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the authorities using the SecurityContextHolder or through the inject Authentication object at your controller.

Find below through the SecurityContextHolder

```
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> list = (Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority>) auth.getAuthorities();

for (SimpleGrantedAuthority permission : list) {
     System.out.println(permission.getAuthority());
}
```

If you need any other information about the logged in user, you can access the UserDetails as follows

```
User userDetails = (User) auth.getPrincipal();
```